# Open satellite imagery

Tags: data, imagery

Our company tracks multifamily development and is relying on opensource satellite imagery to track physical changes at development sites over time. Are there any open source providers (aside from Google Earth, Landsat - which is 30m) that we can leverage internally?

Comment: see http://gisgeography.com/free-satellite-imagery-data-list/

Comment: I think this question would be more on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: 10m Sentinel 2 is available free from [AWS](http://sentinel-pds.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/) or USGS Earth Explorer

Answer (score 2):

There was a talk in Denver 2 weeks ago from a DigitalGlobe employee who stated that their new product SpaceNet on AWS will allow an open source download platform for a lot of DG imagery of some pretty high resolution:

https://aws.amazon.com/public-data-sets/spacenet/

Have a look and let me know if you can get some imagery out of it!